# Definability of orderings on a formally real number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, number-fields

For vector basis $b_1,..,b_n$ on a finite extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, where $-1$ is not a sum of squares, each linear order on $F$ is determined by an order on the basis.  This uses information about where the $b_i$ sit among the rationals, and that information can be gained from Sturm's algorithm applied to any polynomial defining the field.

Is there a good reference for defining/computing orderings on formally real number fields?

Comment: By uniqueness of real closures up to isomorphism, every order structure on a number field (if any exist) arises from an injection into $\mathbf{R}$ as a subfield. That addresses the question at the end, but I'm not sure what the first paragraph (linear orders and Sturm's algorithm, etc.) has to do with this.

Comment: Yes, I know order structures correspond to injections to $\mathbb{R}$.  What I want is an algorithm which takes a linear order on a base for the field and the rational coordinates of an element of the field in that base, and decides if that element is positive in the induced order on the field.

Comment: Choose a primitive element $\alpha$ of $F$ (i.e. such that $F = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$. Let $f$ be its minimal polynomial. Then the data of an ordering of $F$ is equivalent to the data of an interval in $\mathbf{Q}$ which contains a unique root of $f$. Moreover, given such an interval, and any $x \in F$, we can easily compute an arbitrarily small rational interval containing the image of $x$ by expressing $x$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$, and thus determine whether $x > 0$ or not. This is actually how some computer algebra systems, e.g. Sage, compute with algebraic real numbers.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler  That is helpful.  I suppose these calculations have lower than exponential bounds, is that right?  This looks like it will suit my problem setting very well, maybe better than the way I cast the question. Is there a concise source for understanding this?  I fear I would have trouble working through a description of the Sage implementation.

Comment: I agree, of course, that an order of $F$ determines a unique order on the basis, but the converse is not true: take $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ with basis $B=\{\sqrt{2},2\}$. Both orderings on $F$ give the same ordering on $B$.

Comment: Bounds exponential in what?

Comment: @David, I said that badly. I meant "lower than exponential in the numerical magnitude of rationals involved", which I guess can't be the right way to say it.  Better would be "exponential in the binary length of the data."  That is not very precise but is it good enough to make sense?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Yes! I over generalized from the case of a cyclic cubic polynomial with the roots as base. It does extend to the case David gave, of a primitive root -- with its conjugates as basis.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler  Do you want to make your comment using primitive elements an answer?  I see it solves my motivating problem even without bounding the calculation since my context allows an explicitly bounded number of finite choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Originally a comment, reposted as an answer:)

Choose a primitive element $\alpha$ of F (i.e. such that $F=\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$). Let $f$ be its minimal polynomial. Then the data of a field ordering of $F$ is equivalent to the data of an interval in $\mathbf{Q}$ which contains a unique root of $f$. Given any such interval, it's easy to refine it to an arbitrarily small one, algorithmically, just by repeated bisection.

Hence, given such an interval, and any $x \in F$ (expressed as a polynomial in $\alpha$ of degree $< [F : \mathbf{Q}]$), we can easily compute an arbitrarily small rational interval containing the image of $x$, and thus determine whether $x>0$ or not. This is actually how some computer algebra systems, e.g. Sage, compute with algebraic real numbers.

I don't see any nice way of bounding *a priori* the running time of this algorithm in terms of the basis coefficients of $x$, unfortunately.